# A multiplicative magic square

Tags: mathematics, magic-square

How can you transform a given magic square into a square where all the lines are invariant under multiplication?

Answer (score 5):

> Replace each number in the grid with $2^x$ (or $3^x$, etc).

Comment: Ok, this is way better than what I was thinking

Answer (score 0):

The most trivial is to:

> Multiply every cell by zero. But I'm pretty sure that's not the intended solution.

Partial solution involving another thought process:

> I tried with a few examples for 3x3 and 4x4 and it worked. I didn't manage to find a generalization for any nxm magic square. I just don't know how to proof it:
>  You sum it with itself rotated twice when it's 3x3.
>  You sum it with itself vertically mirrored when it's 4x4.
>  [image: 3x3]
>
>  [image: 4x4]
>
>  [image: 4x4 other]